# Change field value in Formilk based on prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm working on a project where if the user toggles something in the parent component, its state is updated and the state is passed to Formik as a prop. In Formik I have a radio button group with two options which have the same name attribute.

I want to hide one of the options and set the field value to the other option that's visible based on changes to the prop value. For instance, if option B is checked, and user makes a selection in the parent component that hides option B, I want to set the field value to that of option A and make it checked.

I have no problem hiding option B based on the value of the prop but am unable to figure out how to set the field value to that of the visible option.

In other words, is there a way to set Formik field values from the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two ways, **first** using standard react class components (with lifecycles). It can be done using `<Formik component={InnerComponent} />` syntax or `withFormik` HOC.

By using class component you can use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) method to call formik's (passed as prop) `setFieldValue` method.

**Second method** can be simpler. `withFormik` HOC has option `mapPropsToValues` allowing to convert prop to value. In this case embeded component can be functional component.